# Didnt get the expected results when calculate Cosine similarity between strings

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate the pairwise cosine similarity between two strings  that are in the same row of a pandas data frame.

I used the following lines of codes:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity


pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.4f}'.format)


df = pd.DataFrame({'text1': ['The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'The red apple', 'The big blue sky'],
                   'text2': ['The lazy cat jumps over the brown dog', 'The red apple', 'The big yellow sun']})


vectorizer = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(df['text1'] + ' ' + df['text2'])


cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(vectorizer)[:, 0:1]


df['cosine_similarity'] = cosine_similarities


print(df)
```

It gave me following output, which seems incorrect:

[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out what I did incorrectly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert, but here's one way to do it.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.4f}'.format)

df = pd.DataFrame({'text1': ['The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',
                             'The red apple',
                             'The big blue sky'],
                   'text2': ['The lazy cat jumps over the brown dog',
                             'The red apple',
                             'The big yellow sun']})

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

# np.hstack([df["text1"], df["text2"]]) puts all "text2" after "text1"
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(np.hstack([df["text1"], df["text2"]]))

cs = cosine_similarity(X)  # full symmetric numpy.ndarray

# The values you want are on an offset diagonal of cs since
# "text2" strings were stacked at the end of "text1" strings

pairwise_cs = cs.diagonal(offset=len(df))
df["cosine_similarity"] = pairwise_cs

print(df)
```

which shows:

```
                                         text1                                  text2  cosine_similarity
0  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  The lazy cat jumps over the brown dog             0.8581
1                                The red apple                          The red apple             1.0000
2                             The big blue sky                     The big yellow sun             0.5000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But do you have any thoughts about why my code didnt work? I am also a beginner and I wanted to learn.

Comment: Also would it be possible, just to perform one comparison per text, rather than performing all pairwise comparisons?

Comment: _"... do you have any thoughts about why my code didnt work?"_ `df['text1'] + ' ' + df['text2']` will concatenate the strings in the columns.  Any comparison of the the strings in the separate columns is lost then.

Comment: _"... would it be possible, just to perform one comparison per text, rather than performing all pairwise comparisons?"_ Yes, but I wonder if it would be any faster since I'm assuming `cosine_similarity` is somewhat optimized.  For example, to calculate the first pair only, it would be `X[0].dot(X[3].T)/(X[0].dot(X[0].T)*X[3].dot(X[3].T)).sqrt()`.  IDK, if there is perhaps another library that may perform the calculation faster and more concisely.